# Chainlink Random Number generator failing with Gas error

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink, random, vrf

I am trying to generate a random number using chainlink VRF

1. i have changed all the address as per goreli
2. I have deployed in goreli testnet and sent some link token to the contract address
3. Clicking on getRandomNumber
   But its throwing error, Please help me to find the mistake.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Are you using the [subscription](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/get-a-random-number/)  or the [direct funding](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/direct-funding/examples/get-a-random-number/) method? You can find examples for each at those links.

Comment: @RichardG I was using direct funding method for this above contract but it didnt worked, now i changed the code to direct funding method and now its working like smooths charm.

Comment: I had same error and solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757900/getting-a-random-number-with-chainlink-vrf/74759256#74759256